# Why does my RPI3 keep restarting?

Tags: raspbian

I have this Raspberry Pi 3 and I haven't used it in 2-3 months but I wanted to revive it by using it as a Home server. So, I booted it up with my Power supply and it tries to boot and after couple of seconds, it keeps on rebooting. I thought my power supply wasn't enough, so I tried it on my Raspberry Pi 2 and it worked fine! I even thought it was a problem with the SD card but it booted fine on my Raspberry Pi 2. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
    Randy

Comment: It may be the power supply as the Pi3 needs more power than the Pi2.

Comment: A slightly defective USB cable could do this also.

Answer (score 1):

Is a [rainbow square visible on the top right hand side?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6fPU.jpg) If so, it is a power issue, you should probably try using a different adapter. For best results, use one rated at least 5V 2A (but you mentioned your other Pi works, so this is unlikely).

To make sure it's not a corrupt file system/SD card try getting a brand new SD card and flashing a new OS.

The Pi2/Pi3 OS should be interchangeable but I would definitely run a `sudo apt-get update` and a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, to make sure it's on the latest firmware.